# C# and jSON is not working

Tags: c#, arrays, json

Need a little help here

So I have a json url and need to get each item into a for each loop

Here is the json

```
{
    "_links": { },
    "count": 9,
    "list": {
        "staff": [
            "staff1",
            "staff2",
            "staff3"
        ],
        "clients": [
            "client1",
            "client2",
            "client3",
            "client4",
            "client5",
            "client6"
        ]
    }
}
```

I have also got the following code in c# but keep getting errors

```
string source;
var sURL = "LINK_TO_JSON_URL";
WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(sURL);
req.Method = "GET";
req.Timeout = 5000;
try
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    {
        source = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
    }
    JToken jObject = JObject.Parse(source);
    string clients = (string)jObject["list"]["clients"];

    //for each loop here

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //error message here
}
```

What is it that I am doing wrong? I have tried to convert string to array and still get nothing.
I want to be able to get each clients names

Cheers

Comment: What are the error messages you are getting?

Comment: Looks like `jObject["list"]["clients"]` would be a `JArray`. You should iterate over that and not cast it to a `string`.

Comment: have you tried this `string[] clients = jObject["list"]["clients"];`

Comment: You cannot cast jObject["list"]["clients"] to string or string array and if any of you had actually attempted to do so, you would know that. Casting to string array is a compile time error. Casting to string is a runtime error. I believe that the return value is a JToken and not a JArray.

Comment: (But you can still iterate over the JToken as demonstrated in crashmstr's answer below, since JToken is a descendant of JArray)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here is some code to show iterating over a `JArray` that contains strings. This code has been tested with your json and outputs each client string.

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(source);

foreach (var client in jObject["list"]["clients"])
{
    Console.WriteLine((string)client);
}
```

Comment: This is actually correct and does not at any point attempt to ridiculously cast an object to another object to which it cannot be cast. +1.

Comment: You sir are a legend. Have a virtual beer on me :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this piece of code

```
#region Model For Deserialize String to Object
    public class Links
    {
    }
    public class List
    {
        public List<string> staff { get; set; }
        public List<string> clients { get; set; }
    }
    public class RootObject
    {
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
        public List list { get; set; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Restfull Respone (String) Convert To RootObject
    public class ConvertStringToObj
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            //Your webReq and Response progress here
            string jsonResponse="";
            var rootObj = (RootObject)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse, typeof(RootObject));
            foreach(var eachItem in rootObj.list.staff)
            {
                var stafName = eachItem;
            }

        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Here is an solution, you can do this via Objects :)

Comment: If you are going to do it that way (sometimes nicer than working with the `JObject` stuff), you should use `DeserializeObject<RootObject>` and then you don't need the cast or the extra parameter.

Comment: Yeap, you are right. But some special case this  typeof(RootObject) parameter needed. Especially convert string to List<Object> type. By the way, I love this object solution to much. Because, everythin is clear....